# Resampling (Upsample) Pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, resampling

Here is a sample dataframe for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

arrays = [np.sort([datetime.date(2016, 8, 31), datetime.date(2016, 7, 31), datetime.date(2016, 6, 30)]*3),
         ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']*5]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15, 4), index=arrays)
df.index.rename(['date', 'id'], inplace=True)
```

What it looks like:

[image]

I would like to resample the `date` level of the multiindex to weekly frequency `W-FRI` via upsampling, i.e., copying from the most recent values `how='last'`.  The examples I've seen usually end up aggregating the data (which I want to avoid) after using the `pd.Grouper` function.

Edit: I have found a solution below, but I wonder if there is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I have found a solution:

```
df.unstack().resample('W-FRI', how='last', fill_method='ffill')
```

but I wonder if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In current pandas version 0.23.3, your method will lead to a warning:

> FutureWarning: fill_method is deprecated to .resample()
>
> the new syntax is .resample(...).last().ffill()

This will not cause warning:

```
df.unstack(level=1).resample('W-FRI').pad()
```

It's better to explicitly state the unstack level (in your case level 1 or -1) IMO